# How to remove duplicate of dropdown when selecting dropdown value

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am quite new to the whole javascript and PHP. I have two issues with my code that i cannot seem to fix.

When i choose a category, it should show a table with the corresponding category. But it is including the dropdown as a duplicate, also there is an error that i can't see why is returned as an "Undefined variable: output in /var/www/html/phpDD.php on line 37" which is: "$output .= "tbody".

i hope you can help me to continue develop! :)

**phpDD.php**

```
<?php

    // include database connection file
    include_once "testSide.php";

    if(isset($_POST['InvestmentName']))
{
    $uid = $_POST['InvestmentName'];
}
    $qu = "select Prod.name, one.yield as yield_one, five.yield as yield_two, ten.yield as yield_three, twenty.yield as yield_four, one.stdev as st_one, five.stdev as st_two, ten.stdev as st_three, twenty.stdev as st_four, one.top1dd as top_one, five.top1dd as top_two, ten.top1dd as top_three, twenty.top1dd as top_four Select *
        from products
        where category_id = $uid) as Prod
    left join;";
        
        
            $result = $conn->query($qu);
            if (!$result) {
                trigger_error('Invalid query:' . $conn->error);
            }
        
            if ($result->rowCount() > 0) {
                $output .= "<table class='table table-hover table-border'>
                                <thead>
                                  <tr>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Afkast sidste år</th>
                                    <th>Genst sidste 5 år</th>
                                    <th>Genst stidste 10 år</th>
                                    <th>Genst sidste 20 år</th>
                                    <th>SR sidste år</th>
                                    <th>SR 5 år</th>
                                    <th>SR 10 år</th>
                                    <th>SR 20 år</th>
                                    <th>DD sidste år</th>
                                    <th>DD 5 år</th>
                                    <th>DD 10 år</th>
                                    <th>DD 20 år</th>
                                  </tr>
                                </thead>";
            while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $output .= "<tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>{$row["name"]}</td>
                  <td>{$row["yield_one"]}</td>
                  <td>{$row["yield_two"]}</td>
                  <td>{$row["yield_three"]}</td>
                  <td>{$row["yield_four"]}</td>
                  <td>{$row["st_one"]}</td>
                  <td>{$row["st_two"]}</td>
                  <td>{$row["st_three"]}</td>
                  <td>{$row["st_four"]}</td>
                  <td>{$row["top_one"]}</td>
                  <td>{$row["top_two"]}</td>
                  <td>{$row["top_three"]}</td>
                  <td>{$row["top_four"]}</td>
                </tr>";
              
                }                       
                "</tbody>";               
                $output .= "</tbody></table>";
                echo $output;
            }else{
                echo "No records found";
            }
        ?>
```

**Index.php**

```
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 50px;">
      <h2 class="text-center">Væg en kategori </h2>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>  
          <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:20px;">
            <form id="submitForm">
              <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control Investment" name="Investment" id="Investment">
                  <option value="">Vælg Kategori</option>
                      <?php foreach($users as $user): ?>
                        <option value="<?= $user['id']; ?>"><?= $user['name']; ?></option>
                      <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div id="show-invest">
          </div>
        </div>    
      </div>
  </body>
</html>

<!---jQuery ajax load rcords using select box --->
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".Investment").on("change", function(){
        var InvestmentName = $(this).val();
        if (InvestmentName !== "") {
          $.ajax({
            url : "phpDD.php",
            type:"POST",
            cache:false,
            data:{InvestmentName:InvestmentName},
            success:function(data){
              $("#show-invest").html(data);
            }
          });
        }else{
          $("#show-invest").html(" ");
        }
      })
  });
</script>
```

**Website**
[image]

**DB**
[image]

Comment: Can you show your database?  Is that the full phpDD.php?  (It doesn't have the "<?php" at the beginning, so I don't think it is)

Comment: Can you show the full phpDD.php

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have not defined `$output` in your script.  You can't have the first instance of `$output` being `$output .=` because the `.=` implies that the variable already exists.

To fix this, add `$output = '';` somewhere before the `$output .=`

For example:

```
<?php

    // include database connection file
    include_once "testSide.php";

    if(isset($_POST['InvestmentName']))
{
    $uid = $_POST['InvestmentName'];
}

    $output = ''; //This is required

    $qu = "select Prod.name, one.yield as yield_one, five.yield as yield_two, ten.yield as yield_three, twenty.yield as yield_four, one.stdev as st_one, five.stdev as st_two, ten.stdev as st_three, twenty.stdev as st_four, one.top1dd as top_one, five.top1dd as top_two, ten.top1dd as top_three, twenty.top1dd as top_four Select *
        from products
        where category_id = $uid) as Prod
    left join;";
        
        
            $result = $conn->query($qu);
            if (!$result) {
                trigger_error('Invalid query:' . $conn->error);
            }
        
            if ($result->rowCount() > 0) {
                $output .= "<table class='table table-hover table-border'>
                                <thead>
                                  <tr>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Afkast sidste år</th>
                                    <th>Genst sidste 5 år</th>
                                    <th>Genst stidste 10 år</th>
                                    <th>Genst sidste 20 år</th>
                                    <th>SR sidste år</th>
                                    <th>SR 5 år</th>
                                    <th>SR 10 år</th>
                                    <th>SR 20 år</th>
                                    <th>DD sidste år</th>
                                    <th>DD 5 år</th>
                                    <th>DD 10 år</th>
                                    <th>DD 20 år</th>
                                  </tr>
                                </thead>";
            while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $output .= "<tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>{$row["name"]}</td>
                  <td>{$row["yield_one"]}</td>
                  <td>{$row["yield_two"]}</td>
                  <td>{$row["yield_three"]}</td>
                  <td>{$row["yield_four"]}</td>
                  <td>{$row["st_one"]}</td>
                  <td>{$row["st_two"]}</td>
                  <td>{$row["st_three"]}</td>
                  <td>{$row["st_four"]}</td>
                  <td>{$row["top_one"]}</td>
                  <td>{$row["top_two"]}</td>
                  <td>{$row["top_three"]}</td>
                  <td>{$row["top_four"]}</td>
                </tr>";
              
                }                       
                "</tbody>";               
                $output .= "</tbody></table>";
                echo $output;
            }else{
                echo "No records found";
            }
        ?>
Index
```

As for the duplicate, you have the main file `testSide.php` being included when you use AJAX to load content.

Comment: Thanks man! It worked now! can you see why it prins two of the dropdowns as well?

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of the duplicate?

Comment: It should be in the picture above the database :) tou can see "vælg en katego" and the dropdown are there two times

Comment: i added a tag "Website" :)

Comment: Can you give me the view source "view-source:URL" in chrome.  It is showing only one for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226179/discussion-between-aft2233-and-seth-b).

Answer (score 1):

> *"Undefined variable: output in /var/www/html/phpDD.php on line 37"*

If you look for the first instance of `$output`, it is:

```
$output .= "<table class='table table-hover table-border'>
```

It is performing two operations in one line: 1) *concatenation*, then 2) *assignment*.

It is understood that, to use a variable in an operation (in this case *concatenation*), it must first be defined. Since that is not the case, we get the error "*Undefined variable: output ...*".

Since the `$output` variable is only used in the `if` block, we can replace the *concatenate-then-assign* line with just an *assignment*:

```
if ($result->rowCount() > 0) {
    $output = "<table class='table table-hover table-border'>
    ...
}
```

However, if the `$output` is `echo()`'d outside the `if` block, then we must declare it outside/before the `if` block:

```
$output = '';

if ($result->rowCount() > 0) {
    $output .= "<table class='table table-hover table-border'>
    ...
}

echo $output;
```